# How to change the background color of a QScrollArea without affecting the scrollbar color?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qscrollarea

I'm using

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
```

to change the background color of a QScrollArea in PyQt5, but that also affects the scroll bar. What is the proper way of just changing the area background color?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea)

class TaskListWidget(QScrollArea):
   def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.content = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.content)
        for _ in range(20):
            self.layout.addWidget(QLabel("task"))
        self.setWidget(self.content)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tasklist = TaskListWidget()
        self.windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.windowLayout.addWidget(self.tasklist)
        self.setLayout(self.windowLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to set the background-color of the QScrollBar to None.

```
self.setStyleSheet(
    """
    QWidget{ background-color: white } 
    QScrollBar{ background-color: none } 
    """
)
```